# How to use random access files to create a program to read and display a file

Tags: c++, randomaccessfile

I’ve started doing C++ and I’ve come across random access files. I have a good understanding of how they work but how would I use them if I want them to read and display an entire file from beginning to end? For example, I am trying to make a program that opens up a menu and gives you options on what to do with a previous file. The options would be:
1.Read and display the entire file from the beginning to the end of file

Read and display the entire file from the End to the beginning of file in reverse order

I understand that for this you would use

```
inf.seekg(0, ios::beg);
inf.seekg(0, ios::end);
```

to move to the beginning or the end of the file. I was wondering how you would use this to read and display a file from beginning to end and from end to beginning in a programs output.

Comment: While you can set the file pointer to a random position into file, you cannot read backwards. If you want to display a file in reverse order you have to read that file from begin to end into a memory buffer. Then you can access it in memory in reverse order. Btw. reverse order... byte for byte reverse or line for line reverse?

Comment: Of course, you could `inf.seekg(-1, ios::end);` then read the last char/byte of file, then `inf.seekg(-2, ios::end);` then read the second last char/byte of file, etc. However, I'm not sure about the performance. I would expect that reading larger portions from begin to end is faster than seeking and reading every single byte from end to begin.